# How can I open EML.XML files in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xml

How can I open [these](https://www.kiesraad.nl/binaries/kiesraad/documenten/rapporten/2017/2/definitieve-kandidatenlijsten-tk-2017/definitieve-kandidatenlijsten-tk-2017/Kandidatenlijsten_EML_TK2017-20170213.zip) EML.XML files? I know how to acces the ZIP... ;-)

Comment: Any text editor should be able to open the .xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just XML files, you can open them in any text editor.

The [specification](https://www.kiesraad.nl/binaries/kiesraad/documenten/formulieren/2016/osv/eml-bestanden/specificatiedocument-eml_nl-versie-1.0a/specificatiedocument-eml-nl-1.0.a.pdf) (PDF) is custom to kiesraad.nl. That's the wonderful thing about XML, you can define your own data structures. And they have. The specs explain what each XML element means, and what can belong where. It'll allow you to write a very accurate parser, if you wish.

There are also formatted PDFs of the data if you want something *you* can read.